# Alert() with dynamic content javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert

What is wrong with `alert({s[prop]})` but fine with this `placeholder={s[prop]}`

It says I am missing a ',' after 's' and ':' after ']'

Comment: Is this part React/JSX? `placeholder={s[prop]}`

Comment: s is an object with many properties

Comment: Oh yes soz it is

Comment: If your post is missing a tag, please edit it and include the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In React, the `{` `}`s around attributes are essentially *expression delimiters* - they indicate that what follows between the brackets is an *expression*. So, if you have `const str = 'foobar'`, then:

```
placeholder={str}
```

evaluates to

```
placeholder='foobar'
```

But, in `alert`, you're not writing JSX - you're writing plain JS. When in an expression context, `{` indicates the start of an object literal. But the following is not a valid object literal:

```
const obj = {
  s[prop]
}
```

because objects require keys and values (usually). Perhaps you wanted to do

```
alert(s[prop])
```

The only time an object literal *doesn't* require a value is when you're using the shorthand syntax, when you have a variable in the current scope and want to define an object with a property with the same name as the variable, and the same value as a variable, eg:

```
const str = 'foobar';
const obj = { str };
```

This results in an object like `{ str: 'foobar' }`.

In any other situation, you'll need to define the property name in addition to the value, eg

```
{ somePropertyName: s[prop] }
```

Answer (score 0):

> alert(s['use your key'])

Please use in this way. Avoid using {} in alert(), If you use you will see [object Object] instead of actual dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
alert(s[prop])
```

In JSX to print any JS variable it must be wrap inside curly braces, but not required when using in JS, `alert` is the JavaScript function.